# JAVA: Replacing number in array, with the numbers position and print out

Tags: java, arrays, replace, while-loop

I have a small problem here. I want to replace all negative numbers in an array with the numbers position. My problem is that the array gets printed out, before the numbers are replaced, and I want to print out the array after it gets replaced... 
Here is my code:

```
public class oppgave33{

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] heltall = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
  int counter = 0;
  int sumNeg = 0;

  while(counter < heltall.length){

    //array print out

    System.out.println("array[" + counter + "] = " + heltall[counter]);


    if(heltall[counter] < 0){
      System.out.println(heltall[counter]);

    }

    //replacing negative numbers

    if(heltall[counter] < 0 ){
      heltall[counter]=counter;
    }
      if(heltall[counter] < 0){
      sumNeg++;
    }

    //negative numbers position print out

    if(heltall[counter] < 0 ){
      System.out.println("Negative numbers position in array is : " + counter);
    }

    counter++;
    }

    //printing out how many negative numbers

    System.out.println("There are : " + sumNeg + " negative numbers.");


    }
  }
```

Final note: if you remove the if setting, where the negative numbers are replaced by their position in array, you will get position to negative numbers printed out, and also how many negative numbers there are. 
I hope you can help me! :) Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39528556/replacing-array-values, but this time with an effort from the asker. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too many redundant conditions in your code. Your attempt is very close, you can simply do the following:

```
while (counter < heltall.length) {
    // if the number is negative, replace it with its index
    if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
        heltall[counter] = counter;
    }
    counter++;
}
// outside the loop
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heltall));
```

Important tip: In such cases, you should **debug** your code. This will help you better understanding the flow of your code, and discover problems that you're not aware of them. I highly recommend you debugging your current code, and only then try to fix it.

Comment: hmmm, but now when i try to compile in terminal there is something wrong with: "System.out.println(Arrays.toString(heltall));" error: cannot find symbol "Arrays"

Comment: @Chris You should import it: `import java.util.Arrays;`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that much of conditions to replace negative numbers. Just replace one by one when you get a negative number in the loop.

**Removing redundancy:** One thing to remember: when you have some statements for same condition, you don't need to do them individually. Write all the statements in same if block.

For example, in your code:

```
if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
    System.out.println(heltall[counter]);
}

if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
    heltall[counter] = counter;
}

if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
    sumNeg++;
}

if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
    System.out.println("Negative numbers position in array is : " + counter);
}
```

Could be replaced by:

```
if(heltall[counter] < 0) { // do all in the same if condition block
    System.out.println(heltall[counter]);
    heltall[counter] = counter;
    sumNeg++;
    System.out.println("Negative numbers position in array is : " + counter);
}
```

**Solution:** Anyway, the whole code could look like this:

```
while (counter < heltall.length) {
    // replacing negative numbers
    if (heltall[counter] < 0) {
        heltall[counter] = counter;
        sumNeg++;
    }
    counter++;
}
System.out.println("There were : " + sumNeg + " negative numbers.");
System.out.println("Array after replacing negative numbers: "+Arrays.toString(heltall));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of your code:

Note: You must place the printing command after the replacement. Code runs step-by-step and in the line order. The statements at the top rows run first, then the lower rows, (sure in order).

```
public class oppgave33{

public static void main(String[] args) {

  int[] heltall = {1, 4, 5, -2, -4, 6, 10, 3, -2};
  int counter = 0;
  int sumNeg = 0;

while(counter < heltall.length){

    if(heltall[counter] < 0 ){

      //replacing negative numbers
      heltall[counter]=counter;

      //counting negative number amount
      sumNeg++;

      //array print out after replace
       System.out.println("array[" + counter + "] = " + heltall[counter]);

      //negative numbers position print out
      System.out.println("Negative numbers position in array is : " + counter);
    }



    counter++;
    }

    //printing out how many negative numbers

    System.out.println("There are : " + sumNeg + " negative numbers.");


    }
  }
```